# Rough times trying to convert string to integers array

Tags: c, arrays, string, integer, cs50

Basically the program will ask for user credit card number, capture it inside a string, convert a string to an integer array (so I can validate credit card number, for later digit sums and multiplying).

I need a variable with integers array and the code below stores ASCII values.

Tried reading lots of posts, but didn't get it.

I'd appreciate any help, so I could sleep again =)
Cordially,

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{

string cc_string;

printf("Please enter a credit card number:\n");

//Captures credit card string
cc_string = GetString();

// Array of credit card digits integers 
int cc_digits[16];

    for (int i = 0; i<= 15; i++)
        {   
            cc_digits[i] = (int) cc_string[i];
            //Just checking what value has been stored
            printf("position %d with %d \n", i, cc_digits[i]);
        }

//to be continued

}
```

Comment: You will run into this same conversion over and over again. It is well worth taking a look at [**ASCII Table & Description**](http://www.asciitable.com/) to understand exactly why *character* `'0'` is actually *decimal* `48`. That is why the conversion `'char_val' - '0'` provides a proper conversion to the decimal value for the character representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `cc_digits[i] = (int) cc_string[i]` try `cc_digits[i] = cc_string[i] - '0'` If you just cast to `int` you'll get the ASCII code for the character, but if you subtract the code of character `0` then you should get the actual digit.

Comment: Grigor, thank you so much. Very helpful indeed, brother.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of casting to int with `(int)`, use [atoi()](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdlib.h/atoi)

Comment: the compiler returns: 
credit.c:21:33: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with &
      [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
            cc_digits[i] = atoi(cc_string[i]);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                                &
/usr/include/stdlib.h:147:30: note: passing argument to parameter '__nptr' here
extern int atoi (const char *__nptr)
                             ^

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, want to share with you guys.Thank you all for the help, time and learnings.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
    long long cc_num;
    int array_dig[15];
    int static sum_evens, sum_odds, sum_tot, valid = 0;
    printf("Enter your credit card number for validation: \n");
    cc_num = GetLongLong();

    for (int i=15; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            array_dig[i] = cc_num % 10;
            cc_num = cc_num / 10;

            //Sanity check
            printf("pos %d = %d\n", i, array_dig[i]);
        }

    //Summing digits
    for (int j=0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            if (j % 2 == 0)
            {
            sum_evens += array_dig[j];

            //Sanity check
            printf("sum_evens = %d/n", sum_evens);
            }

            else if (j % 2 == 1)
                {
                    if (array_dig[j] < 5)
                    {
                        sum_odds += 2 * array_dig[j];

                        //Sanity check
                        printf("sum_odds for char < 5 = %d\n", sum_odds);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sum_odds += (2 * array_dig[j]) % 10 + 1;

                        //Sanity check
                        printf("sum_odds for char >= 5 = %d\n", sum_odds);
                    }
                }
        }

         sum_tot = sum_evens + sum_odds;

         //Validation (if sum % 10 = 0 it is valid)
         valid = sum_tot % 10;
         printf("sum_tot = %d, valid = %d \n", sum_tot, valid);
            if (valid % 10 == 0)
                {
                    printf("Valid credit card \n");
                }
            else
                {
                    printf("Invalid credit card\n");
                }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so soon. =(
Program looses precision when passes values (digits) to the long long variable cc_num.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)

{
    long long cc_num;
    char cc_num_str[15];

    int static sum_evens, sum_odds, sum_tot, valid = 0;
    int static size;
    do
        {
            printf("Enter your credit card number for validation: \n");
            cc_num = GetLongLong();
            sprintf(cc_num_str, "%lld", cc_num);
            size = strlen (cc_num_str);
        }
    while (cc_num < 1 || cc_num > 9999999999999999 || size < 13 || size > 16);

    int array_dig[size];

    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            array_dig[i] = cc_num % 10;
            cc_num = cc_num / 10;

            //Sanity check
            printf("pos %d = %d\n", i, array_dig[i]);
        }

    //Summing digits
    for (int j=0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (j % 2 == 0)
            {
            sum_evens += array_dig[j];

            //Sanity check
            printf("sum_evens = %d/n", sum_evens);
            }

            else if (j % 2 == 1)
                {
                    if (array_dig[j] < 5)
                    {
                        sum_odds += 2 * array_dig[j];

                        //Sanity check
                        printf("sum_odds for char < 5 = %d\n", sum_odds);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sum_odds += (2 * array_dig[j]) % 10 + 1;

                        //Sanity check
                        printf("sum_odds for char >= 5 = %d\n", sum_odds);
                    }
                }
        }

         sum_tot = sum_evens + sum_odds;

         //Validation (if sum % 10 = 0 it is valid)
         valid = sum_tot % 10;
         printf("sum_tot = %d, valid = %d \n", sum_tot, valid);
            if (valid % 10 == 0)
                {
                    //code that will verifies card type (to be written)

                    printf("Valid credit card \n");
                }

            else
                {
                    printf("Invalid. \n");
                }
    return 0;    
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 Enter your credit card number for validation: 
    1234567809874366
    pos 15 = 8
    pos 14 = 3
    pos 13 = 6
    pos 12 = 9
    pos 11 = 5
    pos 10 = 8
    pos 9 = 9
    pos 8 = 0
    pos 7 = 8
    pos 6 = 7
    pos 5 = 6
    pos 4 = 5
    pos 3 = 4
    pos 2 = 3
    pos 1 = 2
    pos 0 = 1
    sum_evens = 1/nsum_odds for char < 5 = 4
    sum_evens = 4/nsum_odds for char < 5 = 12
    sum_evens = 9/nsum_odds for char >= 5 = 15
    sum_evens = 16/nsum_odds for char >= 5 = 22
    sum_evens = 16/nsum_odds for char >= 5 = 31
    sum_evens = 24/nsum_odds for char >= 5 = 32
    sum_evens = 33/nsum_odds for char >= 5 = 35
    sum_evens = 36/nsum_odds for char >= 5 = 42
    sum_tot = 78, valid = 8 
    Invalid.
```